# PHP Updating values in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page where it shows a students details from the database (Mysql) which the student fills in during the registration process.

After logging in I display all the entries made, in a table and give a option to edit the information.

I am finding it difficult to update the information which is edited to the database , as I want the student to remain on the same page.

```
    <?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234') or die('Could not connect');
mysql_select_db('PMS', $connection) or die('Database not found.');
$query = "select * from student_database WHERE student_id=".$id."";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query wrong');
echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><center>";
$i = 0;
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table width="500" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <?php
    while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
        $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
        if ($meta->name != "email" && $meta->name != "password") {
            echo "<tr><td>".$meta->name."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type=text name=\"".$meta->name."\" disabled=true value=\"".$row[$i]."\" /></td></tr>";
        }

        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    ?>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="editbutton"  value="Edit" onclick="editfields()">
```

There is a update button which appears as soon as the edit button is pressed and all the fields become editable (they were set as disabled on page load).

Now my questions is:

How do I update the newly fed information into the database without leaving the page?

Comment: have you tried to use ajax to load the "content" of the page with the edit functions ?

Comment: Kindly clarify the bit "as I want the student to remain on the same page"

Comment: YEs samehere AJAX is what you are looking for. . .

Comment: `<center>` what is this, 1996? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

do update on different page If you fill it is better , then redirect on this page using header and with information data updated successfully